# How to fetch fragment manager without extending the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using libraries to build some cards, my java extends library class now i have requirement to use  FragmentManager in my java class i tried to do that using inner class but getting null pointer exception

Comment: you could just accept it as an outside dependency, as a parameter either to the constructor or a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `Activity` reference: `activity.getFragmentManager()`

If you have a `Fragment` reference: `fragment.getFragmentManager()`

They are both `public` methods, but you'll need a reference to either an activity or fragment.

Also, and though I don't recommend it, if you have a `View` reference, the `view.getContext()` method will *likely* be an `Activity`, so you might be able to cast up and get the `FragmentManager` that way. But this is potentially dangerous, and could stop working at any moment if Android's implementations change, so you should really know what you're doing. Passing an Activity/Fragment reference really is the way to go.

Comment: Pasting the code below :  public class CustomExpandCard extends CardExpand {
    String text1;   
    public CustomExpandCard(Context context,String text1,String text2,String text3,String text4) {
        super(context, R.layout.carddemo_example_inner_expand);
        this.text1=text1; 
    }
   
}    Do i need to create an inner class and passing context into it. Actually i am new to android can u tell me some sample code it will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

`getFragmentManager()` is a `public` `non-static` method of `Activity`. So to get `FragmentManager`, you need to have `activity`'s `context`. So even if you are not extending `activity` class, you need to have its `context`.

Also look at the description of this method, it clears things out.

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this activity.

```
/**
 * Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
 * with this activity.
 */
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    return mFragments.getFragmentManager();
}
```

So without `activity`, `FragmentManger` doesn't exist.